# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class is not found in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I am running a very simple java program, with one package, and a class inside that package, yet it raises a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. This is the program structure:
[image]

The testy.java file:

```java
package loop;

public class Testy {
    
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }

}
```

When I try and run this, though, it raises this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class loop.Testy
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: loop.Testy
```

Even though the package structure is proper. Why is this error getting raised, and what can I do to fix it?

I have tried deleting my run configurations, dis and re enabling "Build Automatically", and experimenting with different values for all the options in eclipse. Nothing seems to work

This is the command line after an automatic boot-up:

```
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_15.0.2.v20210201-0955\jre\bin\javaw.exe 
   -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
   -classpath "C:\Users\myfile\eclipse-workspace\‏First Project\bin" 
   -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages loop.Testy
```

Comment: Eclipse is often tricky to get working properly. How are you attempting to execute the program? If Eclipse is not required you can always execute it from the command line directly assuming you have a newer java jdk.

Comment: I have the loop.Testy.java file selected, and press Ctrl+F11 to run.

Comment: The `src` file is in classpath, so I don't think that's the problem

Comment: Does deleting the run configuration (in _Run > Run Configurations..._) and retrying solve it? If not, please show the command line (in the run configuration there is a button _Show Command Line_) and tell which Eclipse and Java version do you use.

Comment: Java version 11.0.10, Eclipse version 4.19.0

Comment: Did deleting help? Command line?

Comment: Deleting did not help, and This is the command line: `C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_15.0.2.v20210201-0955\jre\bin\javaw.exe
-Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
-classpath "C:\Users\myfile\eclipse-workspace\‏First Project\bin"
-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages loop.Testy`

Comment: Command line looks good. Make sure _Project > Build Automatically_ is enabled and that `C:\Users\myfile\eclipse-workspace` is not on a network drive. If this does not help, tell whether `C:\Users\myfile\eclipse-workspace\‏First Project\bin\loop\Testy.class` exists.

Comment: Build automatically is enabled, and `C:\Users\myfile\eclipse-workspace\‏First Project\bin\loop\Testy.class` does exist.